# How to access/copy the View function?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm currently working on an add in for RStudio which opens an "enchanced" view of a data frame in Shiny, allows you to filter and select columns, then passes that code to the command line wrapped in `View()`.

One feature which was suggested to me was to replace the default `View` in RStudio when the package is loaded to always load my new viewer.

I wanted this, but also to preserve the ability to use RStudio's `View` if you wanted. So I tried code like this:

```
View <- function(data_in, replace = T){
    if (replace){
        print('example')
    }else{
        utils::View(data_in)
}
```

This does not work, however, as `utils::View` is *not* the same as the `View` in RStudio. However, a search for `?View` only gets the utils version. I'm assuming RStudio is overwriting `View` when loading, but I have no idea how to access it. I'd be happy to copy the function into something called save_view (or similar) but don't know how to access it! Entering `View` into the command line gives me the following code

```
function (...) 
.rs.callAs(name, hook, original, ...)
<environment: 0x516d648>
```

But copying that to a new function will just give me something that errors (I'm wondering if it's something to do with the environment the function exists on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RStudio replaces the internal View function with the one you saw.  You can get it using

```
RStudioView <- as.environment("package:utils")$View
```

If you call that one, it should do what RStudio does.

You get the original one using `utils::View`.

Comment: Great thank you! What is happening here? I see it's forcing the utils package to act as an environment, and then extracting the view function... but I don't see what the impact of this is? I guess it's forcing the spreadsheet to open in the r studio environment rather than as a new window?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the source of the View() (from utils):

```
function (x, title) 
{
  check <- Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_SCREEN_DEVICE_", "")
  msg <- "View() should not be used in examples etc"
  if (identical(check, "stop")) 
    stop(msg, domain = NA)
  else if (identical(check, "warn")) 
    warning(msg, immediate. = TRUE, noBreaks. = TRUE, domain = NA)
  if (missing(title)) 
    title <- paste("Data:", deparse(substitute(x))[1])
  as.num.or.char <- function(x) {
    if (is.character(x)) 
      x
    else if (is.numeric(x)) {
      storage.mode(x) <- "double"
      x
    }
    else as.character(x)
  }
  x0 <- as.data.frame(x)
  x <- as.list(format.data.frame(x0))
  rn <- row.names(x0)
  if (any(rn != seq_along(rn))) 
    x <- c(list(row.names = rn), x)
  if (!is.list(x) || !length(x) || !all(sapply(x, is.atomic)) || 
    !max(lengths(x))) 
    stop("invalid 'x' argument")
  if (grepl("darwin", R.version$os)) 
    check_for_XQuartz()
  invisible(.External2(C_dataviewer, x, title))
}
```

And very clearly it's calling the `C_dataviwer` and this is the dataviewer https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205175388-Using-the-Data-Viewer#starting-the-viewer

Edit:

Here's the actual code of `dataviewer` https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/5719361179d1020dc3157c4e24b21bcd17c483e6/src/cpp/session/modules/data/DataViewer.cpp

Comment: This isn’t relevant to RStudio/OP’s question. And in fact if you attempt to call this function from within RStudio you’ll most likely get an error (“X11 is not available”). At any rate, the code you’ve linked to is *not* the code of `C_dataviewer`.