# Rstudio file.edit and utils::file.edit

Tags: r, rstudio, edit

I am working with Rstudio and have written a script which at some point does

```
file.edit('blah')
```

When I run this line a new tab in the IDE opens up titled 'blah' and I am free to edit and save the file. If the file 'blah' existed this then file is the one opened. Otherwise it is temporarily created.

I wanted to include the line in a package I was writing so I did

```
utils::file.edit('blah')
```

This does not produce the same effect however. Instead an Rstudio pop-up Window. If the file 'blah' existed this file is the one opened, otherwise it is temporarily created.

I would like to know, if it is at all possible to configuring `utils::file.edit` to open in the same way that `file.edit` does.

For further information if I type:

```
file.edit
```

I get

```
function (...) 
.rs.callAs(name, hook, original, ...)
```

Whereas, if I type

```
utils::file.edit
```

I get

```
function (..., title = file, editor = getOption("editor"), 
    fileEncoding = "") 
{
    file <- path.expand(c(...))
    title <- rep_len(as.character(title), length(file))
    if (nzchar(fileEncoding) && fileEncoding != "native.enc") {
        tfile <- file
        for (i in seq_along(file)) {
            tfile <- tempfile()
            con <- file(file[i], encoding = fileEncoding)
            writeLines(readLines(con), tfile)
            close(con)
            file[i] <- tfile
        }
    }
    if (is.function(editor)) 
        invisible(editor(file = file, title = title))
    else invisible(.External2(C_fileedit, file, title, editor))
}
<bytecode: 0x000001786f4a17b8>
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

If I do:

```
utils_env<-as.environment('package:utils')
utils_env$file.edit
```

I see

```
function (...) 
.rs.callAs(name, hook, original, ...)
<environment: 0x000001bedbc1b8d0>
```

Which is further confusing, as I would have expected the version of `file.edit` from the package to match the one in the package environment.

So my surface level question is how can I write my package so that Rstudio opens the file for editing the way I want. But the deeper question is *What is going on here?* Does Rstudio overwrite the `file.edit` function at start-up, and then how can I call my preferred version of `file.edit`?

Thanks for taking the time to read, really grateful if you can help.

Comment: yes it does! `my.file.edit <- as.environment("package:utils")$file.edit`

Comment: For anyone who comes to this post and wonders what my above comment is about. Someone asked [does this help answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46953507/how-to-access-copy-the-view-function), but they appear to have deleted their comment. It did help.